# Why does one of these statements compile in Scala but not the other?

Tags: syntax, scala

(**Note**: I'm using Scala 2.7.7 here, not 2.8).

I'm doing something pretty simple -- creating a map based on the values in a simple, 2-column CSV file -- and I've completed it easily enough, but I'm perplexed at why my first attempt didn't compile.  Here's the code:

```
// Returns Iterator[String]
private def getLines = Source.fromFile(csvFilePath).getLines

// This doesn't compile:
def mapping: Map[String,String] = {
    Map(getLines map { line: String =>
          val pairArr = line.split(",")
          pairArr(0) -> pairArr(1).trim()
        }.toList:_*)
  }

// This DOES compile
def mapping: Map[String,String] = {
    def strPair(line: String): (String,String) = {
      val pairArr = line.split(",")
      pairArr(0) -> pairArr(1).trim()
    }
    Map(getLines.map( strPair(_) ).toList:_*)
  }
```

The compiler error is

> CsvReader.scala:16:
>   error: value toList is not a member of
>   (St ring) => (java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.String)    [scalac] possible
>   cause: maybe a semicolon is missing
>   before `value toList'?    [scalac]
>   }.toList:_*)    [scalac]           ^
>   [scalac] one error found

So what gives?  They seem like they should be equivalent to me, apart from the explicit function definition (vs. anonymous in the nonworking example) and () vs. {}.  If I replace the curly braces with parentheses in the nonworking example, the error is "';' expected, but 'val' found."  But if I remove the local variable definition and split the string twice AND use parens instead of curly braces, it compiles.  Can someone explain this difference to me, preferably with a link to Scala docs explaining the difference between parens and curly braces when used to surround method arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the difference is because you are using the operator notation in the first example. If you add an extra set of parentheses it works:

```
def mapping: Map[String,String] = {
    Map((getLines map { line: String =>
      val pairArr = line.split(",")
      pairArr(0) -> pairArr(1).trim()
    }).toList:_*)
}
```

or if you don't use the operator syntax it works

```
def mapping: Map[String,String] = {
    Map(getLines.map({ line: String =>
      val pairArr = line.split(",")
      pairArr(0) -> pairArr(1).trim()
    }).toList:_*)
}
```

I think the problem is that using the normal method invocation syntax has higher precedence than the operator syntax for method calls. This meant that the `.toList` was being applied to the anonymous function rather than to the result of the `map` method call.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use operator syntax, it compiles fine:

```
//Compiles
def mapping: Map[String,String] = {
    Map(getLines.map { line: String =>
          val pairArr = line.split(",")
          pairArr(0) -> pairArr(1).trim()
        }.toList:_*)
  }
```

There is not a problem with how you use the anonymous function, but as Ben mentioned, the syntax of calls `map` without the `.` is not equivalent to the typical Java-style method call.